# Cannot return the values of forms

Tags: php, forms

I am new to php and web programming.

I am programming a website that collects essays. In the submission form, I want the date to be entered by 3 select dropdown forms (day-month-year). I used to add them in a text field and save them as strings in database. I added already hundreds of essays so I am not changing the type of data.

I did the following: 
1- I made a dynamic dropdown using php:

```
function get_dropdown_options( $name, array $options, $selected=null ) {
$dropdown = '<select name="'.$name.'" id="'.$name.'">'."\n";
$selected = $selected;
    foreach( $options as $key=>$option )
{
   $select = $selected==$key ? ' selected' : null;
   $dropdown .= '<option value="'.$key.'"'.$select.'>'.$option.'</option>'."\n";
}

$dropdown .= '</select>'."\n";
return $dropdown; }
```

2- then I made a function to show three dropdown menus for days, months and years.

```
function show_date_dropdown_row($name, $label, $option1, $option2, $option3,  $value = "") {

echo "<tr class=\"".get_row_bg()."\" valign='top'>\n<td><p class=\"rowtitle\">".$label."</p></td>\n"; 
  echo "<td><p>\n";     
  echo get_dropdown_options($name1, $option1, $value1).get_dropdown_options($name2, $option2, $value2).get_dropdown_options($name3, $option3, $value3);
  return $name = $name1." - ".$name2." - ".$name3;
    }
```

3- in the submission form page, I put the following code:

```
show_date_dropdown_row("release_date", "Release Date", $days_list, $months_list, $years_list, "");
```

4- the name "release_date" is then added to the database.

The page shows the three dropdown lists perfectly. But the problem is that the "release_date" in database don't store any value.

I tried the function in step1 and it works perfectly. I know that the problem is in step two, but don't know where.

Comment: where are you defining $name1, $name2 and $name3? also there are better ways in terms of UX to display a date input, I suggest you look for a datepicker plugin

Comment: I didn't define them. Do i have to?

Comment: for the datepicker plugin, its not useful for me because I add essays date back to 80's and 90's so it'll be time consuming.

Comment: Can we see the output of step 3?

Comment: Well how do you expect them to get a value if you don't set one? you should set 'day','month' and 'year' as the names, also it seems you don't have value1, value2, value3 either, so I suggest you just omit them. Finally you're going to have to modify your code that updates the database as now instead of one post value, you'll have 3 that you'll need to concatenate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your return statement inside show_dropdown_row will not provide you with the date you want. That function will run only once when user request for the page.

So instead of $name1,$name2 and $name3 in your get_dropdown_options function you should put values like. day,month and year as names for your select elements.

When submiting your form at on your php script you should catch those value using post or get.
like.

```
$dates=$_POST['year']."-".$_POST['month']."-".$_POST['day'];
```